# using regex to return all text between two different strings, except if it finds a new section

Tags: regex, string-matching

I need to read a text file from the disk and return all lines between two different strings (this part I already solved). But if a new section is found without a E: included, then it shouldn't return anything.

So, I have this text file:

```
[NT_BASIC]
"SYSTEM"            WARNING      1 GB                                       * 0000 2400
"SYSTEM"            MINOR        500 MB                                     * 0000 2400

[OTHERS],[DB2]
"D:"                WARNING      1 GB                                       * 0000 2400
"D:"                MINOR        500 MB                                     * 0000 2400
"E:"                WARNING      1 GB                                     1-5 0700 1700
"E:"                MINOR        500 MB                                   1-5 0700 1700
"F:"                WARNING      5 %                                      1-5 0700 1700
"F:"                MINOR        2 %                                      1-5 0700 1700
"H:"                WARNING      1 GB                                     1-5 0700 1700
"H:"                MINOR        500 MB                                   1-5 0700 1700
```

And, with this expression, I'm able to return all text between [NT_BASIC] and E:

```
(?=NT_BASIC)([\s\S]*?)(?<=E:)
```

However, since there's a new section of information (an empty line, followed by "[" and another section type - in this case "*[OTHERS],[DB2]*"), I want to return nothing.

Is there a way to achieve this using regex?

Comment: could you put your expected output also, it makes it more clear.

Comment: added... thanks :)

Comment: changed the objective... now it's clearer, I think :)

Comment: [https://regex101.com/r/BdM6d2/1](https://regex101.com/r/BdM6d2/1) is this your required output ? why are you searching till E ?

Comment: yes, that's it.. .the goal is this: I need to automatically understand what is included in drive E:. For example, in this case, I would want to know that only "OTHERS" and "DB2" are included there. NT_BASIC should be discarded, because it's not on disk E:

Comment: Do you represent file as an array of lines, notably is that the structure you return to the caller? In that case it is easier to record switches between sections (`[NT_BASIC]`, `[OTHERS],[DB2]`) maintaining a flag for each section in turn whether you have found the target expression (`^"E:"`). Detect this expression by searching the content of a single line.  Discard lines of sections for which the flag does not get set. Bonus: Easily extendable to cater for exclusion criteria and more complex criteria (eg. counting occurrences in a section).

Comment: hmm.. I'm afraid I don't quite follow what you're suggesting  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a negative lookahead if supported excluding matching the lines that are followed by a newline and a `[` char.

```
^\[NT_BASIC](?:,\[[^\r\n\]]*])*(?:\r?\n(?!\r?\n\[).*)*\r?\n"E:"
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `\[NT_BASIC]` Match `[NT_BASIC]`
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `,\[[^\r\n\]]*]` Match a comma followed by an opening till closing parenthesis`[...]`
- `)*` Repeat 0+ times
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\r?\n(?!\r?\n\[)` Match a newline, assert what is directly to the right is not a newline followed by `[`
  - `.*` Match the whole line
- `)*` Close group and repeat 0+ times
- `\r?\n"E:"` Match a newline followed by `"E:"`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rzIqCG/1)

---

Another option is to match all lines that do not start with a whitespace char or a `[` char using a negated character class.

If you also don't want to match the double quotes around the  `"E:"`, you could match until the first occurrence of `E"`

```
^\[NT_BASIC](?:,\[[^\r\n\]]*])*\r?\n(?:[^\s\[].*\r?\n)*.*?\bE:
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Qt6xkZ/1)

Comment: thanks.. it works for the NT_BASIC - it doesn't return anything. But if I change it to "OTHERS", for example (^\[OTHERS](?:\r?\n(?!\r?\n\[).*)*\r?\n"E:"), it should return every line between "OTHERS" and "E:", including those two.. :)

Comment: @AntonioBarrote Do you mean like this? https://regex101.com/r/yWVhi7/1

Comment: can it be done without the " before and after E:? Because I need this to run on powershell, and the command would be: [regex]::match((Get-Content C:\file.cfg, "^\[OTHERS](?:,\[[^\r\n\]]*])*(?:\r?\n(?!\r?\n\[).*)*\r?\n"E:"").Groups[1].Value

Comment: @AntonioBarrote You could for example match the whole line containing the `E:` without matching the double quotes https://regex101.com/r/afYnFk/1

Comment: funny.. on regex101 it works fine. But not on powershell.. :(

Comment: I see that you are using `Groups[1].Value` but the pattern does not contain a capturing group. Can you try it with an inline modifier for multiline and get the match instead of the group? `(?m)^\[NT_BASIC](?:,\[[^\r\n\]]*])*(?:\r?\n(?!\r?\n\[).*)*\r?\n"E:"`

Comment: still not working :(     command is: [regex]::match((Get-Content C:\osit\etc\df_mon.cfg | Where { $_ -notmatch "^#" }), "(?m)^\[OTHERS](?:,\[[^\r\n\]]*])*(?:\r?\n(?!\r?\n\[).*)*\r?\n.*\bE:.*").Groups[1].Value

Comment: @AntonioBarrote Try it like this with the `-Raw` option `[regex]::match((Get-Content -Raw C:\osit\etc\df_mon.cfg), "(?m)^\[OTHERS\](?:,\[[^\r\n\]]*])*(?:\r?\n(?!\r?\n\[).*)*\r?\n.*\bE:.*").value`

Answer (score 0):

I have this:

`(?<=\[NT_BASIC\]\s)([\s\S]*?)(?="E:|\s\[)`

Test: https://regexr.com/51pf4

If you remove the second section, it matches until "E:"

Comment: thanks for the answer.. however, I want to return nothing if a new section is found before the E:  :)